# Button disappear after click on HTML page

Tags: html

I have a page when i click on button it disappear i am using this in anchor tag
When i clik on button it disappears

```
  <!DOCTYPE HTML>
  <html>
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>
  <link type="text/css" href="splashcss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  </head>

 <body>
 <div id="container">
 <div id="image"><a href="overview.html">
  <img src="image/startbutton.png"
    onmouseover="this.src='image/Startbuttonmouse.png'"
    onmouseout="this.src='image/startbutton.png'"/>  

 </a>
 </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're linking to `overview.html`, if the button is not present there, it won't show

Comment: i am not seeing to show over there but it disapears after click and after some time it moves to next page but background remains same but button disappears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the click of image, it lands on the `overview.html` page.

You can see **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GQQEE/)**

Comment: yes i also want this but before moving to overview.html after click image disappears

Comment: It is working fine on browser but on device it moves back